# Split a line network at "T-junctions / 4 way intersections" in the data?

Tags: arcgis-pro, splitting, network

I have a large network of lines (**EDIT clarification: The dataset is not a network, just geometries**). I need to dissolve the lines and split them so each line segment is its full length, but ends where it meets another line.

What I have:

[image: What I have]

What I wish to achieve:

[image: What I want to achieve]

I simply need to dissolve lines that have a common endpoint (the red and green line in the first image), and I need to split the green line where it meets up with the purple line.
My goal is simply to get my network split up into lines with no intersections.

I feel like this should be simple, but splitting lines at vertices also splits every segment into a multitude of line segments. I guess I could try some sort of workaround with extracting vertice points etc, but I hope I am just missing a simple tool in my memory?

I know this can be done manually, but it is not an option with the size of the dataset.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an advance/standard license you can use the editor tool Planarize to introduce a junction between your green and purple line, then feed the results into a dissolve tool with unsplit option checked on to dissolve the red and green line.  For example:

Input is as what you show:

[image: Sample]

Simply select the polylines and run planarize tool as shown below:

[image: Planarize]

Run results of planarize tool through dissolve:

[image: Dissolved]

And you get:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I do have advanced license, but this fails for me. Planerize deletes all attributes that has already been added in editing, so the previous work will be lost. I have a group of non-GIS people classifying the line segments in a web-app, and I wanted to streamline their workflow by simplifying the geometry. I can dissolve on all the required attributes, but once that is done, I still need to split all lines att all intersections.

Comment: You could look into extracting the centroids of the new lines and using that to spatially join back data from the source data?  At some point with the lines you want to merge into a single feature, something will need to take precedence.

Comment: Yes, I am considering different approaches, your suggestion here being one of them. I just wished there was a simple way to identify and split lines into line segments. My data has several attributes, some can be ignored, and some needs to be retained. I am still trying to find the simplest way to approach this.